# Делегирование в UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

Использую `UIScrollViewDelegate` для прослушивания `scrollViewDidScroll` функции делегата вызываются. Как написано ниже:

```
class PViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
}
```

Но когда я создаю пользовательский класс функции не вызываются.

```
class ScrollViewDelegateTop: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
}

class PViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = ScrollViewDelegateTop()
    }
}
```

Comment: поскольку scrollView.delegate создает weak reference к вашему вновь созданному инстансу SrollViewDelegateTop(), то он деаллоцируется как только программа выходит их текущего scope

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Вы могли бы указать как правильно создать делегат?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: постите свой ответ тогда

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko запостил, данное решение имеет право на существование?

Comment: вполне себе нормально

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему созданием экземпляра класса делегата в `ViewController`

```
class ScrollViewDelegateTop: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
}

class PViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollDelegat : ScrollViewDelegateTop!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollDelegat = ScrollViewDelegateTop()
        scrollView.delegate = scrollDelegat
    }
}
```